# Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Permission denied) while executing python in hadoop

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, hadoop-streaming, ubuntu-17.10

[reducer code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1E6ZaIuujSAMMGnvmf4EfOWZdZ4bhN9pt)  [mapper code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ahgKkndqPGwkWQs7R3UFU8PU0R9XsNFQ/view?usp=sharing) [screenshot of command and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cOdt.png)

`Python` files not able to execute while using Hadoop-streaming. I've tried everything including giving executable permission for `mappers` and `reducers`  but its still not working. I am executing this is `Ubuntu 17.10`.

Comment: Share the code you have tried.

Comment: I uploaded the code please help me!!